# symfony custom error pages production environment

Tags: php, symfony

I created custom error pages for symfony.

In development enviroment it works by using the following from the handbook:

```
http://localhost/app_dev.php/_error/{statusCode}
```

This is working.

But now in the production environment.
I prepared the production environment with the following code:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
```

This is not working, I do not get my custom error page but the default one.

I found some articles on stackoverflow but not with the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the standard edition, then `/_error` is mounted under `routing_dev.yml`. That's mean that it's available only on `dev` environment. You can move it from `routing_dev.yml` to `routing.yml`.

```
# app/config/routing.yml
_errors:
    resource: "@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml"
    prefix:   /_error
```

Comment: This not the problem, I already had that in my routing.yml. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: what's the output of `php bin/console router:debug --env=prod`?

Comment: Name                Method   Scheme   Host   Path                      
 ------------------- -------- -------- ------ -------------------------- 
  _twig_error_test    ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}  
  blog_pageNotFound   ANY      ANY      ANY    /{path}                   
 ------------------- -------- -------- ------ --------------------------

Comment: it should works. how did you create the custom error pages?

Comment: Exactly as the symfony handbook explaines: i put the html.twig files in the app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/ directory and its fully working in development enviroment. And in development I change $kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true); and then it's fully working in development

Comment: which are the file name that you put in `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/`?

Comment: error.html.twig, error403.html.twig, error404.html.twig

Comment: so, if you go `http://localhost/test` you see your `error404`, but  if you go `http://localhost/_error/404` you see twig's `error404`?

Comment: No, In development I see with both (http://localhost/test and http://localhost/_error/404) the custom error page.

Comment: what's the problem then? (`http://localhost/test` is the `prod` env,  while `http://localhost/app_dev.php/test` is `dev` env)

Comment: http://localhost/test is also the development enviroment, moving it to my server and excecuting 'php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug', the custom error pages are no longer working and I get a standard 500 error page when running www.xxxxx.be/test, don't understand me wrong, the website itself is working, only not the custom error pages

Comment: when you say that "localhost/test is also the development enviroment" you mean that you change `app.php`? what did you do?

Comment: I meant http://192.168.1.12:8000/app_dev.php/test the custom error page is working, on the production it is not www.xxxxxx.be/test

Answer (score 1):

I have the problem solved.

It was a permission problem on linux.

The file `/var/www/project/var/logs/prod.log` was the problem probably that the error pages could not be logged. Strange that the rest of the website was working.

Error pages are working now.

Comment: What were the permissions/what did you set them to?

Comment: I used chmod 777, I'm not sure this is the right way? I used 'setfacl -dR -m u:$APACHEUSER:rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX project/app/cache project/app/logs' before for the rest of the website. Must I used this for ......../var/logs/prod.log also?

Comment: I don't know. Think I have the same.problem but with 777chmod... will check tomorrow